# Using JPopupMenu as hover-over display still visible after alt-tabbing

Tags: java, swing

I have a page with objects on it. The object locations are defined by `Rectangle2D.Double`. When I move the mouse I check whether or not the a rectangle contains the mouse point.
If yes I want to show a hover-over menu of the object (so far only text).

What I have in the constructor is this

```
annnotationPopupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
annotationTextArea = new JTextArea(5,20);
annotationTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
annnotationPopupMenu.add(annotationTextArea);
```

and if I'm over an object I run this

```
annotationTextArea.setText(annotation.getContent());
annnotationPopupMenu.setLocation(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x+30, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y);
annnotationPopupMenu.setVisible(true);
```

If I leave the object

```
annnotationPopupMenu.setVisible(false);
```

is run. The problem I have now is that when I tab out of the application and the mouse was over an object the JPopupMenu is still visible even though the rest of the application is now behind the window I tabbed to.

What do I need to do that the JPopup menu will either go invisible or at least does not have priority over the window I tabbed to.

Below a MWE which just opens a PopupMenu which stays on top even alt-tabbing:

```
package popupmenutest;

import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class PopupMenuTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    JPopupMenu annotationPopupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
    JTextArea annotationTextArea = new JTextArea(5,20);
    annotationTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
    annotationPopupMenu.setLocation(500, 400);
    annotationPopupMenu.add(annotationTextArea);
    annotationPopupMenu.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe and identifies the platform affected.

Comment: Are you using `setComponentPopupMenu()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513).

Comment: Have you considered making use of the pre-existing tooltip functionality?

Comment: But the object I want to call the 'Tooltip' on is no swing object, it is a class with a rectangle and some other non swing related members. How would I use the tooltip functionality on an arbitrary object?

Comment: So? Is it backed by a Swing component like a `JPanel` or `JComponent`?  Even if you're using custom painting, you can still use tooltips. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130938/get-tooltip-from-jcombobox-renderer/31131215#31131215) example shows you how to customise the text of the tooltip based on the mouse's location and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238676/tooltip-position-for-cell-in-jtable/31238769#31238769) shows how you can set the location of the tooltip

Comment: It takes place in a class that extens JComponent. Could I call the tooltip on the JComponent given the position of the annotation object?

Comment: In theory, yes. Just remember, all the coordinates will be in the `JComponent's coordinate space, so you might need to do some translations

Comment: There is at least one problem with the tooltip: When the text I add to the tooltip is long then I have just one long single lined tooltip that maybe even goes beyond the screen. I've been looking and manual line break solutions but they all look ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by adding the top frame to the `WindowFocusListener` and then on `windowLostFocus` I call the particular pane and set the visibility of the JPopupMenu to false.

Something like this:

```
package popupmenutest;

import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowFocusListener;

public class PopupMenuTest implements WindowFocusListener
{

    public PopupMenuTest()
    {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        JTextArea annotationTextArea = new JTextArea(5,20);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(annotationTextArea); 
        popupMenu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 120));
        annotationTextArea.setText("Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben. Wer diesen Text liest, ist selbst schuld. Der Text gibt lediglich den Grauwert der Schrift an. Ist das wirklich so? "
            + " Ist es gleichgÃ¼ltig, ob ich schreibe: Dies ist ein Blindtext oder Huardest gefburn? Kjift â€“ mitnichten! Ein Blindtext bietet mir wichtige Informationen. An ihm messe ich die Lesbarkeit einer Schrift, "
            + "ihre Anmutung, wie harmonisch ");

        annotationTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        annotationTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        annotationTextArea.invalidate();
        scrollPane.setVisible(true);
        popupMenu.setLocation(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y);
        popupMenu.add(scrollPane);
        popupMenu.pack();
        frame.add(popupMenu);
        frame.addWindowFocusListener(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    @Override
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e)
    {
        popupMenu.setVisible(false);

    }
    private JPopupMenu popupMenu;
    private JFrame frame;
}
```